# RxJava - Merged Observable that accepts more Observables at any time?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I am encountering a need for an `Observable` implementation that holds one or more Observables and merges them. But here is the kicker: I want to *add* more Observables to be merged at any time, and I guess it might as well support removing them too.

For it to be truly effective, all Subscribers must receive notifications from new Observables that are added post-subscription. Unless all the merged Observables are cold and call `onComplete()`, then I guess it is okay to let the subscriptions unsubscribe even if more Observables are added. This is more for merging multiple infinite hot Observables and being able to add more at any time.

```
MergableObservable<MyEvent> allSources = new MergableObservable<>();

//later in application
Observable<MyEvent> eventSource1 = ...
allSources.add(eventSource1);

//and later again
Observable<MyEvent> eventSource2 = ...
allSources.add(eventSource2 );

//and so on
Observable<MyEvent> eventSource3 = ...
allSources.add(eventSource3);
```

I know there are merging operators, but I need a mutable structure. Am I missing something that already exists? I'd prefer to not use subjects unless it is absolutely appropriate for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid Subjects because you want to manually push new `Observable` sources and not generate them "naturally".

```java
Subject<Observable<T>, Observable<T>> o = PublishSubject
    .<Observable<T>>create().toSerialized();

ConcurrentHashSet<Observable<T>> live = ...

o.flatMap(v -> v.takeWhile(x -> live.containsKey(v))).subscribe(...);

Observable<T> inner = ...
live.add(inner);
o.onNext(inner);

//...

live.remove(inner);
```

Comment: Nice. That's pretty clever.

Comment: I have similar issue, can some please explain this ? This is not even valid in rx java 2 Subject<Observable<T>, Observable<T>> o = PublishSubject.<Observable<T>>().toSerialized();

Comment: Explanation: this answer is for RxJava 1. Also please read the [what's different](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subjects-and-processors) wiki section.

Comment: I'm very new to Rxjava. I'm looking at PublishProcessor, but it seems to do opposite to what I need to do. I need multiple publishers with a single subscriber(consumer).

Comment: Please ask a standalone question with all the details.

Comment: @akarnokd Please take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139227/rxjava-2-observables-that-accepts-more-observables-at-any-time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Subjects are the most reasonable way to handle this. I'm open to other answers if anybody knows a better way. It kind of kills me there is not a built-in way to do this. I imagine it would be a common need.

**Kotlin Implementation**

```
class MergingObservable<T> {

    private val subject: SerializedSubject<T, T> = PublishSubject<T>().toSerialized()

    fun toObservable(): Observable<T> = subject

    operator fun plusAssign(observable: Observable<T>) {
        add(observable)
    }

    fun add(observable: Observable<T>): Subscription = observable.subscribe(subject)
}
```