# RxJava -2 Observables that accepts more Observables at any time?

Tags: java, apache-camel, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm currently using rx-java 2 and have a use case where multiple Observables need to be consumed by single Camel Route subscriber. 
Using this solution as a reference, I have a partly working solution. [RxJava - Merged Observable that accepts more Observables at any time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493677/rxjava-merged-observable-that-accepts-more-observables-at-any-time)

I'm planning to use a `PublishProcessor<T>` that will be subscribed to one camel reactive stream subscriber and then maintain a `ConcurrentHashSet<Flowable<T>>` where I can dynamically add new Observable.
I'm currently stuck on how can I add/manage `Flowable<T>` instances with PublishProcessor? 
I'm really new to rx java, so any help is appreciated! This is what I have so far :

```
PublishProcessor<T> publishProcessor = PublishProcessor.create();
CamelReactiveStreamsService camelReactiveStreamsService = 
CamelReactiveStreams.get(camelContext);
Subscriber<T> subscriber = 
     camelReactiveStreamsService.streamSubscriber("t-class",T.class);
}
Set<Flowable<T>> flowableSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Flowable<T>, Boolean>());

public void add(Flowable<T> flowableOrder){
    flowableSet.add(flowableOrder);
}

public void subscribe(){
    publishProcessor.flatMap(x -> flowableSet.forEach(// TODO)
    }) .subscribe(subscriber);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a single `Processor` and subscribe to more than one observable stream. You would need to manage the subscriptions by adding and removing them as you add and remove observables.

```
PublishProcessor<T> publishProcessor = PublishProcessor.create();

Map<Flowable<T>, Disposable> subscriptions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

void addObservable( Flowable<T> flowable ) {
  subscriptions.computeIfAbsent( flowable, fkey -> 
    flowable.subscribe( publishProcessor ) );
}
void removeObservable( Flowable<T> flowable ) {
  Disposable d = subscriptions.remove( flowable );
  if ( d != null ) {
    d.dispose();
  }
}
void close() {
  for ( Disposable d: subscriptions.values() ) {
    d.dispose();
  }
}
```

Use the flowable as the key to the map, and add or remove subscriptions.